# Mongodb - create a new document in an embedded array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have following User model, embeds the Category model,

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include BCrypt

  field :email,           :type => String
  field :password_hash,   :type => String
  field :password_salt,   :type => String

  embeds_many :categories
  embeds_many :transactions
  ....
   end
```

My question is, I just found that if I use the code:

```
me = User.where("some conditions")
me.categories << Category.new(:name => "party")
```

everything works fine, but if I use the .create method:

```
me = User.where("some conditions")
me.categories << Category.create(:name => "party")
```

I will get an exception:

```
undefined method `new?' for nil:NilClass
```

Anyone knows why is that? And from mongoid.org http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/standard.html, I could see that .new and .create actually generates the same mongo command.

Needs help, thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create immediately persist the document into mongo. Since the category document is within another document (as embedded) you cannot save it separately.   Thats why you are getting the error.

> For more clarity, assume embedded document as a field in the parent
>   document which contains sub fields. Now you can easily understand that
>   you cannot save a field without a document. right?

Other hand **new**  initialize the document class and will be only inserted into the parent doc when using <<.

```
Category.create(:name => "party")
>>NoMethodError: undefined method `new?' for nil:NilClass
```

is equivalent to

```
 c = Category.new(:name => "party")
 c.save
 >>NoMethodError: undefined method `new?' for nil:NilClass
```

Hope this helps